# Create a popup inside chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to have a small div like a popup 
on my chrome extension. 
This div needs to have a simple animation and not to have menu bar at all. 
Is it possible to do it with chrome.windows.create
Method ? Is there another way to do it ? 
What I need is similar to pocket's extension popup.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-pocket/niloccemoadcdkdjlinkgdfekeahmflj?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use content scripts. If you have made a trigger the content script is able to change the page. By using that to your advantage you can add a div filled with all of the html you want to add. You can find a in depth example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Tl3OmwrSaM&index=3&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bL9VOMT65ahNEri9uqLWfS).

Comment: Nice video, although has nothing to do with my question.
I know how to right content script I need a way to open a custom popup.